# OSX ssh: Connection closed by [IP]

Tags: macos, networking, mac, ssh, network-shares

So when I try to ssh from one of my mac to another mac like this:

```
ssh root@macpro.local
```

I get:

```
Connection closed by 192.168.1.64
```

I tried:

```
ssh -vvv root@macpro.local
```

and get:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to macbookpro.local [192.168.1.64] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/Andryuwka/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/Andryuwka/.ssh/id_rsa type 1  
debug1: identity file /Users/Andryuwka/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Andryuwka/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Andryuwka/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by 192.168.1.64
```

Any ideas???

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same issue with 'ssh localhost'

Comment: I know it was 11 years old thread but have you found the solution? I can't connect to all server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that the ssh server did not accept the kind of authentication the ssh-client wants to use.
Or that root is generally not allowed for ssh access.
The better way to find a solution is to access the ssh.log on the ssh-server. There you will find detailed information why the connection establishment is rejected.

ciao
ryder

Comment: where can I find this ssh.log on the ssh server?

Comment: this depends on the Mac OS X version you use. I can find the infos on Version 10.10.X in /var/log/system.log. Did you also remeber to allow the ssh login via System Preferences? See here for details how to do this: http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/30/remote-login-ssh-server-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while ago, this helped me:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3008731

tl;dr: The permissions of the file /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key should be 700 otherwise the ssh connection will fail.

To fix:

```
sudo chmod 700 /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key
```

Comment: thank you for reply but it didn't help.. In fact I have even the 600 rights for this key (it shouldn't be executable so 600 is totally enough) and it still doesn't work...

Comment: Thanks. Exactly my problem. My keys were 600 and although the mac ssh client would prompt for the password, I was getting "Connection closed" once it was entered. Chmod'ing to 700 fixed it.

Comment: didn't work for me on Mojave 10.14